# Using extern in C doesn't work as expected

Tags: c, makefile, extern

I have created two files:

tunables.h

```
#ifndef TUNABLES_H
#define TUNABLES_H

void tunables_load_conservative();
void tunables_load_aggressive();

extern int timer_x;
#endif /*TUNABLES_H */
```

and tunables.c

```
#include "tunables.h"

int timer_x;

void tunables_load_conservative(){
     timer_x = 3;
}
void tunables_load_aggressive(){
     timer_x = 1;
}
```

All the other files of my project includes "*tunables.h*". When I load the project both A.c and B.c calls *tunables_load_conservative* but if, after a while, I call in file A.c *tunables_load_aggressive()* in file B.c the *timer_x* remains 3. Why?

This is my Makefile:

```
INCLUDE=`pwd`/include
GCCFLAGS= -ansi -O3 -pedantic -Wall -Wunused -I${INCLUDE} -DDEBUG 
GCCOTHERFLAGS= -ggdb -pg

all: A B

A: A.o tunables.o
    gcc -o A ${GCCFLAGS} ${GCCOTHERFLAGS} tunables.o

B: B.o tunables.o
    gcc -o LBfixed ${GCCFLAGS} ${GCCOTHERFLAGS} tunables.o

A.o: A.c
    gcc -c ${GCCFLAGS} ${GCCOTHERFLAGS} A.c

B.o: B.c
    gcc -c ${GCCFLAGS} ${GCCOTHERFLAGS} B.c

tunables.o: tunables.c
    gcc -c ${GCCFLAGS} ${GCCOTHERFLAGS} tunables.c

clean:
    rm -rf *.o A B
```

Comment: Please, tag your make-related questions properly (with [make] tag).  More info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24030/why-do-they-specify-makefile-tag-instead-of-make/26567#26567

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've got two separate processes, A and B. The `extern` declaration does not set up shared memory across processes, but instead allows different compilation units *within the same process* to access the same variable.

To share a variable across processes, you will need to use system-dependent IPC methods.

Comment: Omg your right! -_-
I can't notice it because I've created a shell script which run both processes in automatic. :P